# Pandas working with a csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am very new to Python. I am using Pandas to edit a csv file and I have found a function that does the job. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to modify the function as to not update the last 2 columns on the spreadsheet, which are named (ty Daniel Himmelstein) 'Start_X', and 'Start_Y'. I need it to leave blank spaces, they will be filled in with new data later. Thank you,

example of the starting spreadsheet:

```
AK      MINE    VET                                     X       Y
1016649 0       90;59,180;26,270;39,0;9,270;20,0;17,    482547  1710874
```

example of how it needs to be formated:

```
AK      MINE    VET   VET_2     X       Y
1016649 0       90    59        482547  1710874
1016649 0      180    26
1016649 0      270    39 
1016649 0        0     9 
1016649 0      270    20
1016649 0        0    17
```

Here is the code:

```
def tidy_split(df, column, sep='|', keep=False):
    """
    Split the values of a column and expand so the new DataFrame has one split
    value per row. Filters rows where the column is missing.

    Params
    ------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        dataframe with the column to split and expand
    column : str
        the column to split and expand
    sep : str
        the string used to split the column's values
    keep : bool
        whether to retain the presplit value as it's own row

    Returns
    -------
    pandas.DataFrame
        Returns a dataframe with the same columns as `df`.
    """
    indexes = list()
    new_values = list()
    df = df.dropna(subset=[column])
    for i, presplit in enumerate(df[column].astype(str)):
        values = presplit.split(sep)
        if keep and len(values) > 1:
            indexes.append(i)
            new_values.append(presplit)
        for value in values:
            indexes.append(i)
            new_values.append(value)
    new_df = df.iloc[indexes, :].copy()
    new_df[column] = new_values
    return new_df
```

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using the `csv` module?  It's really the one stop shop for manipulating csv files in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have edited my question to add an example of my spreadsheet. I could not find an example in the help files or cook book that aided in formatting the spreadsheet into the new arrangement. I need to explode one cell in a column to many. I tried asking a question on here and my question was given a negative number and no one helped after several days, so I was left to my own accord and this is what I was able to find. I would be very grateful I you had a better way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing might be better handled with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module. Pandas is great for analyzing and manipulating data, but in this case I would properly format the file before loading into a DataFrame.

You could do,

```
import csv

# Where the new data will be stored
data = []

# Open up the csv file
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    # Go through each row
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        # Break up the row based on the columns
        ak, mine, *vet, x, y = row

        # Get VET and VET_2
        v12 = [v.split(';') for v in vet]

        # Create new rows with split values of `vet`
        for j, (v1, v2) in enumerate(v12):
            if j == 0:
                new = [ak, mine, v1, v2, x, y]
            else:
                new = [ak, mine, v1, v2, None, None] # Leave blank spaces after first value

            data.append(new)

# Write out to a new csv file
with open('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # Write header
    writer.writerow(['AK', 'MINE', 'VET', 'VET_2', 'X', 'Y'])
    # Write data
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Using this input `file.csv`:

```
AK,MINE,VET,,,,,,X,Y
1016649,0,90;59,180;26,270;39,0;9,270;20,0;17,482547,1710874
```

I get the following output `new_file.csv`:

```
AK,MINE,VET,VET_2,X,Y
1016649,0,90,59,482547,1710874
1016649,0,180,26,,
1016649,0,270,39,,
1016649,0,0,9,,
1016649,0,270,20,,
1016649,0,0,17,,
```

After your csv file is formatted 'correctly', loading into pandas will be much easier.

Comment: I am getting a TypeError: expected at least 1 arguments, got 0 for the line "writer = csv.writer()" and it is generating a blank csv titled new_file, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try it out now. Before I didn't see the `,` between the `;` in your example spreadsheet.

Comment: thank you for working with me. I am getting error ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack, for line: 'for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(v12):' I tried changing a few things but I do not have the skill set to properly debug the code.

Comment: No problem - I think the header/first row in the csv file needed to be skipped, just updated.

Comment: I am still getting the same error of need more than 1 value to unpack for line "for j, (v1, v2) in enumerate(v12):"

Comment: What is the value of `v12`? I've updated the answer with the input and output I used. Can you check that the input matches yours? Last question is what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @obreach we are using the exact same input. I doing a copy and past on your code. The only thing that I am changing is there is an "*" in the #break up the row based on the columns that is causing a syntax error. When I run the code I am getting the same error for the for j, (v1, v2) in enumerate(v12): its still giving a ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. I dont know if its because there are 2 variable, the v1, and v2 or what. Thank you for the continued assistance. I am using Pyhton 2.7 for compatibility with ArcGIS

Comment: Okay that makes sense then [extended tuple unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) is new in Python 3 but in 2.7 you could assign each of those variables individually so that `ak = row[0]`, `mine = row[1]`, `vet = row[2:-2]`, `x[-2]`, `y[-1]` on separate lines to replace `ak, mine, *vet, x, y = row`

Comment: I made the suggested changes and Im still getting the same error `ValueError: too many values to unpack` for the line `for j, (v1, v2) in enumerate(v12):` i guess its a compatibility issue with v2.7?

Comment: Try printing the result of `v12` and `vet`. `v12` should be a list of lists like this `[['90', '59'], ['180', '26'], ['270', '39'], ['0', '9'], ['270', '20'], ['0', '17']]`. we are unpacking each of the lists into `v1` and `v2` by doing `(v1, v2)`. If those lists contain more than two elements you will get that error meaning something is wrong with the split and the input data might not be the same.

Comment: All right we are cooking now. Its working. There were double quotes around just the vet column that were not visible in excel. I am getting another error `TypeError:'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` for line `with open ('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:` I checked the help files for the csv module and I believe this argument was introduced after v2.7. So I deleted this call and the exported csv is double space (there is a blank line between each row) is this an excel quirk? or a product of deleting the `newline` arg?

Comment: Haha. Another Py2-3 issue. Use `with open('new_file.csv', 'wb') as f:` instead. For future questions use python-2.7 or python-3.x in the tags as opposed to just python. That should help a little bit I think.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is [DataFrame.stack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), which changes the shape of the DataFrame from having all the "vets" in one row to each "vet" in a separate row.

Once you have the right shape, you can continue on to splitting the data further. This should get you started:

```
s = df.VET.str.split(",").apply(pd.Series).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s = s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(";"))).dropna()
result = df.drop("VET", axis=1).join(s)
```